# Angular2 unit test with Karma and Jasmin - "encountered a declaration exception"

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have created an angular 2 component and now I'm trying to create a unit test for my component using Karma and Jasmin, but when I execute my unit test I'm getting excption as 
[encountered a declaration exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LdwA.png)

My Spec file is as below

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { PageTitle } from '../../../components/title/title.component';

it('true is true Out ', () => expect(true).toBe(true));


describe('PageTitle (inline template)', () => {

   let comp: PageTitle;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<PageTitle>;
   let de: DebugElement;
   let el: HTMLElement;

   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [PageTitle],
   });

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageTitle);

   comp = fixture.componentInstance;

   de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));

   el = de.nativeElement;

   it('true is true in', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Has the PageTitle component linked html template and/or css file? If so, that's the problem. Angular is loading them via async calls and your tests run in sync mode right now. Proper setup for testing of component should be something like this:

```
describe('PageTitle', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule(({
        imports: [],
        providers: [],
        declarations: [
            PageTitle
        ]
    }));
});

it('should render component', async(() => {
    TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageTitle);
        let nativeElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
 });
```